# XML Writer Namespaces

Tags: xml, vb.net, svg

I am trying to make a SVG file. this is my current code to write the root element:

```
     ' Write the root element.
        .WriteStartElement("svg")

        'atributes in elemenent + namespace
        .WriteAttributeString("width", SVGWidth)
        .WriteAttributeString("height", SVGheight)
        .WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", Nothing, "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")

        .WriteEndElement()
```

when I run the XML looks like this:

```
<svg width="1920" height="1080" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

but I want to end up with:

```
<svg width="1920" height="1080" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

But when I remove the "xsi" from my vb.net code it results in an error. how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you added the name space when you created the start element?

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7579ed08(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public void WriteStartElement(
    string localName,
    string ns
)
```

like so:

```
.WriteStartElement("svg", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
```

Then remove the line where you are attempting to set the namespace later on?

Comment: if I try that I get an Exception Unhandled: System.Xml.XmlException: 'The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' within the same start element tag.'

Comment: Apologies. I have updated the answer to suggest you set the namespace when you start the element